# Submit a link using javascript or jquery without refreshing a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a link which invokes an API which saves a session. Suppose my API be present on http://www.example.net and my link is as below :

```
 <a href="http://www.example.net" >Click here </a>
```

Now i don't want to refresh the page. Just use JQuery or Javascript to simply execute the link and give an alert like "Action Succesfull". I don't see the point of using AJAX as I don't require any database actions from my side. Thanks

Comment: using ajax to database action is just optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of AJAX is not to do database actions, its to comunicate with the server without needing to reload the page. I think your description qualifies for the use of AJAX, since you do expect a answer from the server, and you do not want to reload the page.

You could also open a iframe, or a new window, but ajax might be the solution here.

Keep in mind you need to cancel that event when you click on the anchor.

So, with ajax you could so something like:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var href = this.getAttribute('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: href,
    success: function(text) {
      alert(text);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked however after the alert it is redirecting to that page which I don't want. Asyou mentioned I need to cancel the even, can you specifically mention how ?

Comment: okay just adding return false, sort things up. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need an ajax call. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "Post",
    url: "http://www.example.net",
    success: function () {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error");
    },
    finaly: function () {
        alert("Finish");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use onclick event if you don't want to use AJAX

```
<a href="http://www.example.net" onclick="event.preventDefault();">Click here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an ajax call when click on button submit or the link. Here is the code :

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.example.net",
        type: "POST",
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data,textstatus,jqXHR)
        {
            alert("Success");
        }

    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "your link";
    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response.
       }
    });
    return false;
```

});